# I need to read a trace log by excluding some lines. How can I do that in a sh file to which I pass a date?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to filter some lines from a log. 
What I thought was like: 
"file 1 <---- log without some lines"

I'd like to leave workspace clean though, so how can I do this (at all) while not leaving trace behind?

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: nothing, I'm new at programming. I'm trying to clean that log because I have to read some for issue throubleshooting.

Comment: You can login to the system, and use `grep` for filtering purposes. Be aware that this command uses so-called "regular expressions", which gives a special meaning to characters like "[", "]", "\", "*", .... If you might need such characters in your filter, I'd advise you to use `fgrep`.